# Comparing two BitmapSources

Tags: .net, wpf, image, bitmap, motion-detection

Just wondering whether there is a way to compare two different bitmapsources in WPF?

My scenario is that Im trying to make a simple motion sensor on a webcam and am just taking shots from the webcam periodically. Now need to take the bitmapSources retrieved from the shots and check if there are any deltas between them (i.e. Something has moved in the camera feed).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/comparingimages.aspx

Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Imagio
{
    public class ComparingImages
    {
        public enum CompareResult
        {
            ciCompareOk,
            ciPixelMismatch,
            ciSizeMismatch
        };

        public static CompareResult Compare(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
        {
            CompareResult cr = CompareResult.ciCompareOk;

            //Test to see if we have the same size of image
            if (bmp1.Size != bmp2.Size)
            {
                cr = CompareResult.ciSizeMismatch;
            }
            else
            {
                //Convert each image to a byte array
                System.Drawing.ImageConverter ic = 
                       new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();

                byte[] btImage1 = new byte[1];
                btImage1 = (byte[])ic.ConvertTo(bmp1, btImage1.GetType());
                byte[] btImage2 = new byte[1];
                btImage2 = (byte[])ic.ConvertTo(bmp2, btImage2.GetType());

                //Compute a hash for each image
                SHA256Managed shaM = new SHA256Managed();
                byte[] hash1 = shaM.ComputeHash(btImage1);
                byte[] hash2 = shaM.ComputeHash(btImage2);

                //Compare the hash values
                for (int i = 0; i < hash1.Length && i < hash2.Length 
                              && cr == CompareResult.ciCompareOk; i++)
                {
                    if (hash1[i] != hash2[i])
                        cr = CompareResult.ciPixelMismatch;
                }
            }
            return cr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know why but everytime the bitmapsources are PixelMismatch even when they seem to be identical. Im gathering there could be a small  difference in the image that cant be seen by the naked eye. Is there anyway to set a threshold so that it takes small deltas into account?

Comment: It could have something to do with header information. If they had different timestamps, that would be enough to throw it I would think. I don't think the author addressed that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a faster example deep in the discussion thread of the last one. See if that works any better.

```
public sealed class ImageHash
{
    private static SHA256Managed _shaM;
    private static SHA256Managed shaM
    {
        get
        {
            if (_shaM == null)
                _shaM = new SHA256Managed();

            return _shaM;
        }
    }

    private static System.Drawing.ImageConverter _imageConverter;
    private static System.Drawing.ImageConverter imageConverter
    {
        get
        {
            if (_imageConverter == null)
                _imageConverter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();

            return _imageConverter;
        }
    }

    public Image Image { get; private set; }

    private byte[] _Hash;
    public byte[] Hash
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Hash == null)
            {
                _Hash = (byte[])imageConverter.ConvertTo(Image, typeof(byte[]));
                _Hash = shaM.ComputeHash(_Hash);
            }

            return _Hash;
        }
    }

    public ImageHash(Image image)
    {
        this.Image = image;
    } 
}

public static class ComparingImages
{
    public enum CompareResult
    {
        ciCompareOk,
        ciPixelMismatch,
        ciSizeMismatch
    };

    public static CompareResult Compare(ImageHash img1, ImageHash img2)
    {
        CompareResult cr = CompareResult.ciCompareOk;

        //Test to see if we have the same size of image
        if (img1.Image.Size != img2.Image.Size)
        {
            cr = CompareResult.ciSizeMismatch;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < img1.Hash.Length && i < img2.Hash.Length
                              && cr == CompareResult.ciCompareOk; i++)
            {
                if (img1.Hash[i] != img2.Hash[i])
                    cr = CompareResult.ciPixelMismatch;
            }
        }
        return cr;
    }
}
```